# Olá, gostaria de saber se é confiável utilizar o express-session em ambiente de produção

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo em node e preciso de pacote para autenticação de login...

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado para produção pois pode causar memory leak ao alocar, pois como é default do node não tem nativo um garbage collector ou algo do tipo para gerenciar a memoria e remover os objetos inutilizados, muito provável que ocorra erros.

como diz no proprio artigo do npmjs recomendável para desenvolvimento e debugging

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Comment: Tem alguma indicação para essa função?

Comment: acredito que qualquer um que não use, MemoryStorage, ou melhor use de acordo com seu banco como oracle-session ou postgres-session.

Comment: uma dica pra entender melhor, é que sessões sempre são alocadas via server side, caso tenha usado alguma vez javaweb ou php se usa recuperar dados da sessão atual ou alocalos, pratica bem comum.